# Spring validation и собственные валидаторы

Tags: java, spring

В процессе реализации kv-хранилища встала задача ограничить использование символов в передаваемом ключе. Я написал собственный валидатор, наследующийся от `org.springframework.validation.Validator`, объявил его, как `@Component`, однако магии не произошло, и он не вызывается. Сама текущая конфигурация Spring, насколько понимаю, "под капотом" использует Hibernate Validator. ЧЯДНТ и как мне добавить произвольный валидатор к уже существующим?

Answer (score 1):

В интернете повсюду встречается версия с InitBinder и ручной валидацией, которая, как оказалось, прекрасно работает и в автоматическом режиме:

```
@RestController
class MyController {
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(new MyCustomValidator());
    }
    ...
}
```